# amp-html: Use query param in amp-list src

Tags: html, amp-html

I have an amp page that is called on:

`https://expample.amp.com?id=1234abc`

*(Not the real url.)*

```
<amp-list src="https://some.external-url.com/?dataid=NEEDS_ID"
  layout="responsive"
  items="Result"
  width="100"
  height="100" 
>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
  <p>{{FullName}}</p>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

I want my `id` query param to be injected into the src of the amp-list tag at `NEEDS_ID`.

I already checked the [QUERY_PARAM docs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#query-parameter) but couldn't understand what exactly I'm supposed to do.

I've already tried `src="https://some.external-url.com/?dataid=QUERY_PARAM(id)"` but that didn't work.

Any pointers/references?

My silly-and-dumb solution to this was writing an EJS node server, that parses a `<%= query.id %>` in that url and then sends that page to the client. Is that the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do strongly suppose that the call to the Url independent to the AMP Page, results in valid json data. 
If this is the case, you may face following problems:

1. CORS
2. your result data is somehow corrputed

As for me, this saved me a lot of time:

```
public function getData(){

   echo header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amp-YOUR-SITE');
   echo header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   echo json_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://expample.amp.com?slug=1234abc
```

```
<amp-list id="time"
            layout="fixed-height"
            height="18"
            src="https://api.exemple.com/posts?slug=QUERY_PARAM(slug)"
            binding="refresh"
            data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM"
            single-item
            items=".">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
```

Comment: hi, have you found solution for this, i have same problem that i want to pass query params from one amp page to another amp page, i can send params with form but i can't access it in another page